# Outlook VBA Type mismatch (error 13) when initializing handler for Sent Mail folder

Tags: vba, types, outlook, handler, mismatch

This is my first thread on the forum so I hope i do everything as is needed.

Since a few years we use a vba outlook macro at our firm to send our sent mails to a folder. The folder is specified when pressing the SEND button. When we created the macro, we used to save the file directly after pressing send, but then only a draft file was saved to the specified folder. Herefore we initiated a handler to check when the mail is added to the Sent Mail folder so we could save this mail to the specified folder. Since yesterday, only some of my colleagues started getting a Type mismatch error while running this macro. Today another couple of colleagues is having this issue as well. Most of us can still use the macro without having any errors.

I narrowed the problem down to the initialize_handler itself by creating a much easier macro. So now when sending any email, I initialize a handler for the items in my Sent Mails folder. When an item is added to the Sent Mails folder, a messagebox should appear telling me an item is added.

The type mismatch error is created on "Set myOlItems = ...."

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub


Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal ObjectSent As Object)
    MsgBox "Item is added to Sent Mails"
End Sub
```

I hope someone has a solution to this. I wasn't able to find out what could trigger the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the reference is broken (Tools, References).

Comment: I would worry about what `GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)` returns.  It returns nothing useful on my system because I do not have a default Sent Items folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting from breaking the chain of property and methods calls by declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code. So, we will be able to find out which property or method calls fails.